# Clear windows command prompt screen using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way of clearing the command prompt screen in windows using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: If keyboard shortcuts are a must for some reason you can always cook up an AutoHotkey script that sends `cls<Enter>` to the open command prompt window.

Comment: Simple use powerhsell. Type posershell in windows command prompt and then use (Ctrl + L) Keyboard shortcut key. After this your black cmd screen will got clear. If you don't want to be on powershell then simply type exit to switch back to windows cmd prompt mode.

Answer (score 218):

NO, But you can use `CLS` command to clear the whole screen, <kbd>Esc</kbd> (Escape) key will clear the input line.
In addition, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will move the cursor to a new blank line.

Comment: in powershell you can use also `clear`

Comment: I think I understand why people like to alias `clear` in linux to `cls` for the consistency between systems!

Comment: Typing 'cls' + `Enter` (Return) is 4 keystrokes. That's pretty close to the 2 or probably 3 you'd need for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Dvaeer with a keyboard shortcut I could e.g. clear the terminal without removing the command I was typing - please don't assume there's only the one use case you can come up with

Answer (score 32):

If you really really want to do that **with a keyboard shortcut** (myself included) you might turn to using [**autohotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and write a little script like this:

```
; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Cntr-L should clear screen
; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^L::
Send cls{Enter}
return

#IfWinActive
```

**what the script does ...**

- first look if one is within console application
- if <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is pressed
- write *`cls`* to the console and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: You might want to use [`SendInput`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail)

Comment: Also `#IfWinActive Command Prompt` will prevent overriding shortcuts for other console applications like bash

Comment: must say, this makes me smile every time I use it. TY @petermeissner

Comment: Doing ```SendInput {Escape}``` before ```SendInput cls{Enter}``` makes sure the line gets cleared before adding the cls command.

Answer (score 3):

So long i also research but found best way to achieve this by defining Doskey Macro

i defined macro like this

> doskey 1=cd\ $T cls

this will do two things by simple writing 1 and hit enter

1. Bring you on clean Command route
2. Clear entire screen

Note: you can add multiple desire command under one macro by separating them with $T

Comment: Maximum answers are already given but I can give you a small hack is to just switch to powershell via windows cmd