# New commands creation in windows for windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

How do I create a keyboard shortcut for a command in the Windows command prompt?

For example, to clear the Windows command prompt, the command normally used is `cls` - analogous to the `clear` command in Linux. I want create a keyboard shortcut for this. Ideally, I'd like to create the shortcut using `ctrl+ L` since this keyboard shortcut also works to run the `clear` command in the Linux command prompt.

Is that possible to create the new commands for Windows command prompt?

Comment: Are you looking to create new commands or new keyboard shortcuts?  Please edit your questions and provide the necessary clarification required to answer your question.

Comment: AT Ramhound obviously a keyboard shortcut that runs the cls command would satisfy what he is asking for. He even gave an example - that example.

Comment: this may help https://superuser.com/questions/585238/clear-windows-command-prompt-screen-using-keyboard-shortcuts   and funnily enough AT ramhound you actually commented on an answer on that question a year ago